# setDrawableByLayerId not works with transparent default drawable

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to set drawable picture dynamically inside `layer-list` of my current project. I made the minimal test case as follows.

For the activity, it's just an `onCreate` function:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.btn_draw_activity_dyn)

    val drawBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.draw_btn)
    drawBtn.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Gotta you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    val layerDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.start_icon_drawable_dyn) as LayerDrawable
    layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.drawPic1, ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@MainActivity, R.drawable.bodhi))
}
```

The layout xml file (`btn_draw_activity_dyn.xml`) is just a `<Button>` , and I need to set `drawableStart`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/draw_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dynamic Button"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/start_icon_drawable_dyn"
        />
```

And the finally the `start_icon_drawable_dyn.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                    android:width="3dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <size
                    android:width="40dp"
                    android:height="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/drawPic1"
            android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</layer-list>
```

What I expected on the icon is( Please ignore the text):
[image]

But actually it shows:
[image]

PS: On using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` , I need to update the `layer-list` into several items later, for example:

```
<item android:id="@+id/drawPic1"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

<item android:id="@+id/drawSun"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:height="15dp"
        android:width="15dp"/>
```

[image]

And the pictures inside `layer-list` would be retrieve from backend server, it might not be suitable to set in the static way.

Comment: you might need to set Drawable for btn too `drawBtn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( layerDrawable, 0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doing a mistake here after creating your new drawable you're not applying it into your button.

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()
```

This function only accepts drawable or resource int as its parameters, after creating your new drawable set the new drawable into your button but this approach is not quite well in this scenario.

To get what you desired you just need to modify your start_icon_drawable_dyn.xml file a little that's all you need.

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <size
                android:width="40dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@+id/drawPic1"
        android:drawable="@drawable/iR.drawable.bodhi"/>
```

Just change this

```
 <item android:id="@+id/drawPic1"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

To this

```
<item android:id="@+id/drawPic1"
        android:drawable="@drawable/iR.drawable.bodhi"/>
```

**Updated**
As for dynamic image add this.

```
drawBtn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( layerDrawable, null, null, null)
```

After creating the new image.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.btn_draw_activity_dyn)

val drawBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.draw_btn)
drawBtn.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Gotta you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

val layerDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.start_icon_drawable_dyn) as LayerDrawable
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.drawPic1, ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@MainActivity, R.drawable.bodhi))
drawBtn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( layerDrawable, null, null, null)
}
```

Comment: The drawable file would be determined in runtime, for example get from server. I think it might be hard to set in the static way.

Comment: In that case, you are forgetting to set the new drawable which is made by adding the new image in it.

Just add this line after creating the new drawable will fix your problem.
drawBtn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( layerDrawable, null, null, null)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, from my understanding, `drawableStart` should do what `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds ` expected to do, I was wondering why we need to use that together?

Comment: @lit2019 You're are absolutely right, We can define it in the XML tag by `drawableStart `  or programmatically `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`. But in your case after creating the new image you're not setting it to your button drawable start you're just creating the new image that's it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are inserting the image into layer drawable it's not refreshing the view. That's why it look as before.

It's not a good approach I guess. Better Go with this when you want to update the image.

1. Make 2 durable files. one with oval and one with the image.
2. When want to update it update with this line of code.

   view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_checked, 0, 0, 0);